# Is this view style possible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I need a screen like this: Always on the top, there's a search bar, Always. Right beneath, there's a navigation controller. Is this possible? I have tried resizing the navigation controller in IB but I can't re-size it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  You will have to construct the interface in code, however.  Your main view controller should have two instance variables: the first should be a search bar, and the second should be a navigation controller.  Then, in `-viewDidLoad`, add the search bar and the navigation controller's view as subviews to the main view controller's view.  The result will look like this:
[image]

You can download the Xcode project here: http://www.mediafire.com/?36dswv4u0le447k

Comment: @Krishnabhadra: Check out AppShopper: http://itunes.apple.com/app/appshopper/id387037496?mt=8.  Their app does the same thing, but instead of having a search bar above the navigation controller they put an ad view.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly simple, but this is possible. What you need to do is make the root view controller a plain view controller, containing a UIView. That view contains the search bar and a "holder view". At the point where you would add the nagivigation controller's view to the window, you instead add it to the holder view.

[image: The result]

I created this using the standard navigation controller template. I modified the app delegate as follows:

```
//header
{
    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    UIViewController *rootVC;
    UIView *holderView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIViewController *rootVC;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBOutlet UIView *holderView;

//implementation
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    UIView *temp;
    temp = navigationController.view;
    CGRect f = holderView.frame;
    f.origin = CGPointZero;
    temp.frame = f;
    [holderView addSubview:temp];
    [window addSubview:rootVC.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

An image of the IB hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: Holy cow! A first-gen iPhone!

Comment: @Josh I'm pretty sure it's at least a 3G, if not a 3GS.

Comment: I thought they had a flat front bezel...oh well.

Comment: @Josh Actually, you were right. I guess apple is just really lazy about updating their images (that does explain why the iPhone 4 looks almost identical to the iPad). For anyone who wants their own original iPhone, this is the simulator in the iOS 4.0 sdk.